# Flutter Form currentState on multiple tabbar NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'currentState' was called on null

Tags: flutter

I have a page with 3 tabbar. On my app I have 2 modes, insert and edit mode. On insert mode currentState bypass through form validation but on the edit mode I got NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'currentState' was called on null. I understand the problem, as I am trying to call the following:

```
List<dynamic> _treatment = form.fields['treatment'].currentState.value;
```

which is in the second tab and I am on the first tab. Same occurs with the 3rd Tab. If I go to 2nd & 3rd tab and then tap the save button I am not getting any error as all the form's variable are created. So, my question is how can I bypass this situation? Help will be highly appreciated as I am a newbie on Flutter. The user of my app can tap the save button while he/she is on any tabbar. On Edit mode I can't prevent for form validation as it's already done on insert mode. Below is my save part code:

```
      Future _saveForm() async {
        final form = _formKey.currentState;
        if (form.validate()) {
          //_formKey.currentState.save();
          _validate = false;
          print('saved');

          form.save();
          List<dynamic> _treatment = form.fields['treatment'].currentState.value;//this make problem as this is in tab 2
          print(_treatment);

          String treatment;
          _treatment.forEach((dynamic treat) {
            if (!treat.contains('FormBuilderFieldOption')) {
              if (treatment == null) {
                treatment = treat.toString();
              } else {
                treatment = treatment + ',' + treat.toString();
              }
            }
          });

          final int prefs = await Preference.getInt('userid');
          final int _loginUser = prefs;
          String _visithealthfacility =
              form.fields['visithealthfacility'].currentState.value.toString();
          if (_visithealthfacility == 'null') {
            _visithealthfacility = null;
          }
          String _bloodinstool = form.fields['bloodinstool'].currentState.value;
          if (_bloodinstool == null) {
            _bloodinstool = 'No';
          }
          String _fever = form.fields['fever'].currentState.value;
          if (_fever == null) {
            _fever = 'No';
          }
          String _other = form.fields['other'].currentState.value;
          if (_other == null) {
            _other = 'Disoriented';
          }
          String _ocv = form.fields['ocv'].currentState.value;//this makes 

problem as it's in tab 3
      if (_ocv == null) {
        _ocv = 'No';
      }
      final Country _country = form.fields['country'].currentState.value;
      final District _district = form.fields['district'].currentState.value;
      final Governorate _governorate =
          form.fields['governorate'].currentState.value;
      final HealthFacility _healthfacility =
          form.fields['healthfacility'].currentState.value;
      final ORT _ort = form.fields['ort'].currentState.value;
      final Village _village = form.fields['village'].currentState.value;
      final CTC _ctc = form.fields['ctc'].currentState.value;
      final CaseData _caseData = CaseData(
        id: widget.caseData.id,
        age: form.fields['age'].currentState.value,
        bloodinstool: _bloodinstool,
        comment: form.fields['comment'].currentState.value,
        countryId: _country.id,
        ctcId: _ctc != null ? _ctc.id : null,
        dehydration: form.fields['dehydration'].currentState.value,
        diarrhoea: form.fields['diarrhoea'].currentState.value,
        districtId: _district.id,
        fever: _fever,
        gender: form.fields['gender'].currentState.value,
        governorateId: _governorate.id,
        healthfacilityId: _healthfacility.id,
        hospitalization: form.fields['hospitalization'].currentState.value,
        month: form.fields['month'].currentState.value,
        ocv: _ocv,
        ortId: _ort != null ? _ort.id : null,
        other: _other,
        outcome: form.fields['outcome'].currentState.value,
        stoolsample: form.fields['stoolsample'].currentState.value,
        symptoms: form.fields['symptoms'].currentState.value.toString(),
        treatment: treatment,
        villageId: _village.id,
        visithealthfacility: _visithealthfacility,
        vomiting: form.fields['vomiting'].currentState.value,
        username: _loginUser,
        selected: 0,
      );
      print(_caseData.toString());
      _caseDataBloc.updatecaseData(_caseData);
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/caselist');
    } else {
      _validate = true;
      FlushbarHelper.createError(
        message: 'Mandatory fields are missing',
        title: 'Please fill the mandatory fields.',
      ).show(context);
      print('validation problem');
      setState(() {
        _autoValidate = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

Actually, this is not related to code but I think technique to handle form state in tabbar. Please see this gif file [Video showing the problem](https://mega.nz/#!6psyxCZB!bA_C4N4Q7PGmDYrNP6a8GwGLFso7Dq3sOSIRGPaIhHY)

Comment: We can help you better if you post more code. That will helps us understand your problem better.

Comment: I edit my question with some code.

Comment: What is the value of `form.fields`?

Comment: form.fields=24. 24 form fields.

Comment: I don't get it. Are you saying the value of `form.fields` is `24`(a integer)? I see in the code you do something like `form.fields['treatment']`. How does an integer have a field like `treatment`?

Comment: form.fields.length is 24. "Value of form.fields" can you please explain what it mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196148/discussion-between-10101010-and-shariful).